# Trigger which calculate values and add it to table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, triggers

I am trying to wright trigger which will insert missing values in table. I am Using SQL Server Express
I have table

```
create table test 
(suma int ,
summ_year int,
summ_month int 
);
```

then I insert one testing value

```
INSERT  into test (suma)values (4951)
```

Than I create trigger which should calculate values based on `summ` value which in table

```
create trigger updatetest
on test
AFTER update
as update test
set summ_year = round(suma*1.85,0 ),summ_month = round(summ_year/12,0)
```

where `1.85` is it fixed value and `12` is months

than i do update suma

```
update test  set suma = 4950
```

and select  to check how does it works

```
select * from test
```

return from select looks like this `4950    9158    NULL`
However second part of my trigger which should calculate `summ_month = round(summ_year/12,0)` return me NULL value.

also when I runn this select

```
select summ_month = round(summ_year/12,0) from test
```

It is working. 
Any ideas how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use computed columns:

```
create table test 
(suma int ,
summ_year as round(suma*1.85,0 ),
summ_month as round(round(suma*1.85,0 )/12,0) 
);
```

No trigger, no muss, no fuss.

As to why your `UPDATE` isn't working? The expressions in the `SET` statement are meant to be computed as if they're evaluated in parallel. They're certainly not evaluated from left to right. So, at the point at which you're computing `summ_month = round(summ_year/12,0)`, `summ_year` hasn't been updated yet and is still `NULL`.

A nice consequence of this behaviour is that to swap the value of two columns, you need only write:

```
UPDATE tab SET a = b, b = a
```

And it does the right thing.

If you do want (for some odd reason) to continue to perform these calculations in a trigger, you'll have to do as I did for the computed columns up at the top - repeat the expression for computing the year value in calculating the month value:

```
update test
set summ_year = round(suma*1.85,0 ),summ_month = round(round(suma*1.85,0 )/12,0)
```

Comment: Problem is users can add only suma value, they are not allowed to add any other data into table, because of that i need trigger which will update this data based on suma which user provide.

Comment: @AndreyIvanov - my example up at the top allows users to only use the `suma` column. `summ_year` and `summ_month` become computed columns. SQL Server takes care of calculating them for us, and they're always right. No need for a trigger at all.